# Are there any interesting modules out there dealing with inverse images of functions?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

I just found myself writing some code like the following:

```
import Prelude hiding (id, (.))
import Control.Category
import Control.Monad ((<=<))

-- | Intended law:
--
--     map forward . backward == id
--
data Invertible a b = 
    Invertible { forward :: a -> b
               -- Maybe switch from [a] to Monad m => m a? (Requires RankNTypes)
               , backward :: b -> [a] }

instance Category Invertible where
    id = Invertible id (:[])
    f . g = Invertible { forward  = forward f . forward g
                       , backward = backward g <=< backward f
                       }
```

I've tried searching Google for uses of the terms "inverse image" or "preimage" in pages about Haskell, but no luck there.  Have any of you trod the path that I'm trodding now and discovered the lay of the land?

I've already worked out that `Invertible a` is not a `Functor`, because when you try to implement `fmap :: (a -> r) -> Invertible a b -> Invertible a r` there is no sensible value for `backward . fmap f` (no sensible function of type `(a -> r) -> (b -> [a]) -> r -> [a]`).  But maybe there are some other interesting operations on this that I'm just not aware of.

Comment: I guess, going just by types, you'd want the law to be something like `map forward . backward == return`. Do you not want a roundtrip law for the other direction? Why do you need the list at all? (If you agree with my proposed law, then `backward` must always return a singleton list anyway.)

Comment: @DanielWagner your proposed rule brings a lot of structure (it makes it a groupoid after all), but is probably not what the OP wants.  The preimage should be a set of values not a single value.

Comment: ..so a better law would be `nub . map forward . backward == return`, but that only works for lists. If the structure in question were a set, then Daniel's law would be correct. (I'm _not_ advocating adding an Eq or Ord context.) There's no roundtrip law for the reverse direction because `backward` can genuinely produce multiple elements. They'd only be the same after mapping `forward`, but that's covered by the first roundtrip law.

Comment: You can get more functorial behaviour if you use a bijection instead of an ordinary function (variously implemented as things like `Bij (a->b) (b->a)`). However, since you're clearly interested in fucntions with no inverse, it would be better to do exactly as you did, and declare the Category instance.

Comment: @AndrewC: actually, the `nub` is not necessary if the type truly represents a function `f :: a -> b` together with its inverse image `f' :: b -> [a]`. Why? Because `f` partitions `a` into disjoin subsets for each value of type `b`. I.e., for each `x :: a` there is exactly one `f x :: b`, so correspondingly there cannot be two distinct `y, y' :: b` such that `elem x (f' y) && elem x (f' y')`

Comment: @sacundim most of what you say is true, but if you find the inverse image of an element b under a non-injective function, as a list rather than as a set, then map the original function over that set, you get multiple copies of the element b because the result is a list, not a set. Example: f=square. Then  map f $ (preimage f) 4 == map f [-2,2] == [4,4]. You need to take the nub of this to get the same result as return would give. I'm saying that if the disjoint subsets aren't singletons, mapping f over them won't be singletons either, so take the nub.